# Trouble scraping phone numbers from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I've been trying to extract every single phone number from a website that deals in properties (renting/buying houses,apartments, etc).

There's plenty of categories (cities, type of properties) and ads in each of those. Whenever you enter an ad, there's obviously more pictures, descriptions, and a phone number at the bottom.

This is the site in question. 
https://www.nekretnine.rs/

I wrote a python script that's supposed to extract those phone numbers, but it's giving me nothing. This is the script.

I figure it's not working cuz its looking for that information from the home page, and the info is not there, but I just can't figure out how to include all those ads across all those categories in my loop. Don't even ask about API, they have none. I mean, I crashed their website with the original, sleepless script.

```
for i in range (1,50):

    url = ("https://www.nekretnine.rs/"+ str(i))
    page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    x = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"label-small"})
    time.sleep (2)
    for item in x:
        number =item.find_all("form",attrs = {"span":"cell-number"})[0].text
        data.append((number ))
        print (data)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the relevant part of the HTML source.

Comment: You can see the python code above, and the html looks like this


   ``` <form action="/form/show-phone-number/mob/NkOfk32ofPL" method="POST" data-dynamic-form="show-phone-number">
                            <span class="cell-number" data-phone-number-container>xxxxxxxxx</span>
                            
                        </form>```

Answer (score 1):

If the content you need is not on the home page, you should use beautifulsoup to find the links to other pages that you need, then post a request to get that html and look for the information there

Comment: Ok, but I was just wondering if I'm supposed to use BS to point to ALL the ads (there's literally hundreds of thousands). That's my problem, all the ads have separate pages for them. I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: That's up to you really, whichever ads you want info for you'd have to navigate to. There are selectors you can use in bs to narrow it down based on html tags to just the ones you want but you'd have to loop through all of the ones you do want

Answer (score -1):

For anyone stumbling here, I found the answer

https://webscraper.io/

This browser script has everything I needed, it's simple, no coding required, minus some regex if you need it